# Every time when users click on the add bank of each row then It should be started from 01 number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button called `Add partner`. When you click on this button then it will display dynamic row something like this.

[image]

After displaying the row, I clicked on `Add Bank`. It will display like this.
[image]

So my final output is till now

[image]

**Note:** After clicking on "Add Bank" It generates the dynamic number which is in the first column.

```
user-10-02-01
```

It will increase depending upon how many banks the user want to add.

```
user-10-02-01
user-10-02-02
user-10-02-03
```

Just image the user added three banks.

There is no issue till now.

Now the user clicks on `Add partner` again and it displays the new row
[image]

After that, The user clicked on `Add Bank` but this time I am getting a wrong dynamic number in the first column. 
[image]

It's displaying `user-10-02-04` It should be displayed `user-10-03-01`.

My main concern is, Evey time when users click on Add Bank of each row then It should be started from 01.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".dynamicform"); //Fields wrapper

  var add_button = $(".click_partner"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  a = 1;
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment

      a++;
      //$("input[id^=medication_name]").focus();
      $(wrapper).append('<div class="clearfix"></div><div class=" custom_fields medication_info"><div class=" row"><div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="label" id="unique">ID ' + x + ':</div></div> <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="order[]" value="user-10-' + inner(a, 2) + '" class="form-control"></div></div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control"><option disabled="">Choose</option> <option value="" selected>Bank one</option><option value="">Bank two</option><option value="">Bank three</option></select></div> </div> <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><a href="#" class="new_add_bank bankLink" id="' + x + '">Add Bank</a> <div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control"><option disabled="">Choose</option> <option value="" selected>Bank one</option><option value="">Bank two</option><option value="">Bank Three</option></select></div> </div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control"><option disabled="">Choose</option> <option value="" selected>Bank one</option><option value="">Bank two</option><option value="">Bank three</option></select></div></div>  <div class="i-imgset remove_field"><img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/I/R/h/v/h/g/remove-icon-md.png" alt="remove"> </div></div></div>');
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('.click_partner').closest('.custom_fields').remove();
    x++;
  });



  var innercoutner = 0;

  $(wrapper).on('click', '.new_add_bank', function() {
    innercoutner++;
    $(this).closest('.row').append('<div class="clearfix"></div><div class="  medication_info"><div class=" row"> <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="order[]" value="user-10-02-' + inner(innercoutner, 2) + '" class="form-control"></div></div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control"><option disabled="">Choose</option> <option value="" selected>Bank one</option><option value="">Bnak two</option><option value="">Bank three</option></select></div> </div> <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control"><option disabled="">Choose</option> <option value="" selected>Bank one</option><option value="">Bank two</option><option value="">Bank three</option></select></div> </div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control"><option disabled="">Choose</option> <option value="" selected>Bank one</option><option value="">Bank two</option><option value="">Bank three</option></select></div></div><div class="i-imgset remove_field"> <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/I/R/h/v/h/g/remove-icon-md.png" alt="remove"> </div></div></div>');


  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.medication_info').remove();
    x--;
  });

  // increment==============================================
  function inner(k, width, t) {
    t = t || '0';
    k = k + '';
    /* 
        return n.length >= ? n : new Array(w widthidth - n.length + 1).join(z) + n; */
    return k.length >= width ? k : new Array(width - k.length + 1).join(t) + k;
  }

});
```

```css
.i-imgset {
  width: 30px;
}

.i-imgset img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="dynamicform">
  <div class="click_partner"> <input type="button" name="parner" value="Add Partner"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the counter value with length of `medication_info` presented row

**Explanation**

1. store the id value on while `medication_info` append via `data-id`.Then you could use this `data-id`   on bank row adding.
2. For  match respected box & row use [`$(this).closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".dynamicform"); //Fields wrapper

  var add_button = $(".click_partner"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  a = 1;
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment

      a++;
      //$("input[id^=medication_name]").focus();
      $(wrapper).append('<div class="clearfix"></div><div class=" custom_fields medication_info" data-id="'+inner(a, 2)+'"><div class=" row"><div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="label" id="unique">ID ' + x + ':</div></div> <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="order[]" value="user-10-' + inner(a, 2) + '" class="form-control"></div></div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control"><option disabled="">Choose</option> <option value="" selected>Bank one</option><option value="">Bank two</option><option value="">Bank three</option></select></div> </div> <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><a href="#" class="new_add_bank bankLink" id="' + x + '">Add Bank</a> <div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control"><option disabled="">Choose</option> <option value="" selected>Bank one</option><option value="">Bank two</option><option value="">Bank Three</option></select></div> </div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control"><option disabled="">Choose</option> <option value="" selected>Bank one</option><option value="">Bank two</option><option value="">Bank three</option></select></div></div>  <div class="i-imgset remove_field"><img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/I/R/h/v/h/g/remove-icon-md.png" alt="remove"> </div></div></div>');
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('.click_partner').closest('.custom_fields').remove();
    x++;
  });




  $(wrapper).on('click', '.new_add_bank', function() {
    var innercoutner = $(this).closest('.medication_info').find('.medication_info').children('.row').length+1;
    var c = $(this).closest('.medication_info').attr('data-id');
    $(this).closest('.row').append('<div class="clearfix"></div><div class="  medication_info"><div class=" row"> <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="order[]" value="user-10-'+c+'-' + inner(innercoutner, 2) + '" class="form-control"></div></div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control"><option disabled="">Choose</option> <option value="" selected>Bank one</option><option value="">Bnak two</option><option value="">Bank three</option></select></div> </div> <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control"><option disabled="">Choose</option> <option value="" selected>Bank one</option><option value="">Bank two</option><option value="">Bank three</option></select></div> </div><div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 "><div class="form-group"><select name="parner[]" class="form-control"><option disabled="">Choose</option> <option value="" selected>Bank one</option><option value="">Bank two</option><option value="">Bank three</option></select></div></div><div class="i-imgset remove_field"> <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/I/R/h/v/h/g/remove-icon-md.png" alt="remove"> </div></div></div>');


  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.medication_info').remove();
    x--;
  });

  // increment==============================================
  function inner(k, width, t) {
    t = t || '0';
    k = k + '';
    /* 
        return n.length >= ? n : new Array(w widthidth - n.length + 1).join(z) + n; */
    return k.length >= width ? k : new Array(width - k.length + 1).join(t) + k;
  }

});
```

```css
.i-imgset {
  width: 30px;
}

.i-imgset img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="dynamicform">
  <div class="click_partner"> <input type="button" name="parner" value="Add Partner"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Give me some time to check your answer

Comment: Yes, your snippet is working correctly. But I have one more issue in this.. check in the second row I is  user-10-03 but after a click on add bank, it displaying user-10-02-01. It should be user-10-03-01

Comment: Yes, that's perfect. It's working. Can you explain to me what script you changed?